# Datatable row-wise iteration and printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, itext, stringwriter

I have a `datatable` that I need to iterate row-wise and print it using iTextSharp in ASP.NET using C#.

For each row retrieved in parent `datatable` **dt**, I print a child table **dt_child**. The **dt_child** is being printed perfectly. But the rows of parent **dt** are not printed in table fashion.

I am currently using the code specified below. But I need better code. As the **dt** isn't being displayed properly.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {

    //The way I print the dt row needs to be changed
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
       stringWrite.Write(dr[dc]);
    }

    //Code Below this works perfectly
    key=dr["key"].ToString();
    dt_child = getDataTablebyProcedure("ChildProcedure",key);
    stringWrite = getStringWriterbyDataTable(dt_child, stringWrite);

    }
```

[image: Issue]

Comment: There are no iTextSharp classes visible in the code you show. Thus, no one can help yet. Most likely the actual iTextSharp objects and their uses are hidden in that `stringWrite` object and `getStringWriterbyDataTable` method.

Comment: For reference, those methods are from this earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23235519/231316