# iTextSharp Pdfwriter document footer data is overlapped with document data

Tags: asp.net, itext, pdf-writer

I'm printing a PDF document which contains multiple pages and every page must have a footer.But when i print the main body content of the document is printing on the footer area also. how to make the document to go to the new page just before the footer (without overlapping on the footer).

Comment: Er... Did you define the bottom margin large enough to accommodate for the footer? If not, why not? And why do you post a question without showing any code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting margins, headers and footers for PDF without overlap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284550/setting-margins-headers-and-footers-for-pdf-without-overlap)

Comment: As you don't show any code, we can merely guess what you are doing wrong.